# При пагинации EF выдаёт ошибку Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2008

Я использую следующий код для пагинации в EF Core:

```
 int page = 1, rowPerPage = 5;
 int count = ctx.Specialty.Count();
 int start = page * rowPerPage;

 var Select = ctx.Specialty.OrderByDescending(u => u.IdS)
            .Skip(start)
            .Take(rowPerPage)
            .AsEnumerable();
```

Использую SQL Server 2008 и Visual Studio 2017, проект ASP.NET Core.

Получаю следующиую ошибку:

> Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'. Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement

Как исправить данную проблему?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'. Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement "in Entity Framework core"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53349099/5752652) от участника  [@Alireza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10464947/alireza).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53349099/5752652

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существует параметр совместимости (`UseRowNumberForPaging`) для подобного случая, может быть сконфигурировать либо в DbContext:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var coonectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=AppDb01;Integrated Security=True";
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(coonectionString, builder => builder.UseRowNumberForPaging());
}
```

Либо в Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var coonectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=AppDb01;Integrated Security=True";
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(coonectionString, builder => builder.UseRowNumberForPaging()));
}
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/54200998/5752652 от участника  [@Elliott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384916/elliott).</sub>